# Query SQL [PSQL]

Tags: sql, psql

I need help with SQL ... I would like to know if it was possible to find the nation (s) that have the highest number of teams .... (a nation has a team if it has at least one driver of that nation in a team) ...

```
f1 driver ( id_driver , driver_name , team , country )
```

I managed to write the command that gives me the number of teams for each nation (I think that's right) ..... I can't understand how and where to use the 'max' command ... can you help me?

```
SELECT (country) ,count(team) 
FROM driver
GROUP BY country;
```

Answer (score 0):

in that solution you don't need max ,only you have to sort the result :

```
SELECT (country) ,count(distinct team) 
FROM driver
GROUP BY country
order by count(distinct team) DESC
```

and if you want the nation with the highest number of teams :

```
SELECT (country) ,count(distinct team) 
FROM driver
GROUP BY country
order by count(distinct team)  DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: thanks for the help .... I have some observations to make ... the second solution you proposed does not work, or rather from the database that I have it must restore me 2 countries but it returns me only one .... the first works but in part .... let me explain better. For example I have 3 athletes from the same country in 2 different teams ... the query will not tell me that that country has 2 teams but 3 because the number of drivers counts ...

Comment: by changing limit number you can return any number of rows you want, also updated the answer to match what you need

Comment: thanks for the explanation ... I wonder if something else can be used instead of 'limit' ... in such a way that you only have the country / countries with more teams and not the whole list ...